# SQL-запрос для обновления текущих значений

Tags: sql

Начну с того, что в SQL и вообще таблицах я полный валенок. Нужен вроде бы простой совет как обновить текущие значения в строках таблицы. Структура следующая: есть таблица strings в ней следующая структура полей: id, locale, value.

Например:

```
'text1', 'ru', 'text 1'
'text1', 'en', 'text 1'
```

Мне нужен пример SQL запроса, в котором будет поиск по id с учетом locale и замена текущего value на мое значение - так же этот запрос нужен быть рассчитан на одновременную замену в нескольких значениях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновление записи по id и locale

```
UPDATE strings SET value = 'yourvalue'
WHERE id='yourId' and locale = 'yourlocale'
```

P.s. очень странно, что у тебя id является строкой.

Comment: Не понял как тут менять value, но если упростить задачу и свести до замены по id без учета locale, то как будет выглядеть?

Comment: @L3n1n тут конечно ошибка, в SET должно быть `value='new val'` если без учета locale, то просто не пишите условие по locale в where

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.